# drawLine is not displaying

Tags: java, swing

I am having a little issue with trying to draw a simple line.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I can't find anything online to help me.

```
package practice;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Practice extends JPanel {

    public void PaintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(1, 1, 50, 50);
        System.out.println("called");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new Practice());
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled the method's name: it's `paintComponent` beginning with a lower case p.

Case matters, especially in this case, where you want polymorphism to call "Practice's" `paintComponent` to be called, not JPanel's.

By the way, you should use the `@Override` tag on top of your public void `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method (Your IDE would have flagged your method not to be an override of any existing method).